# Escaping strings

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm using PDO and was under the impression that prepare escaped apostrophes but I can see that isn't the case. what do I use to escape my strings for apostrophes?

---

```
$sql = 'SELECT test FROM test WHERE id = :id';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':id' => 1));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code? Are you using prepared **statements**?

Comment: Start with [the basics](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) (look for Example #2).

Comment: @netcoder, I think you'll see that my example is right out of example 2. It doesn't work and the apostrophes are not escaped.

Comment: It's because there is no apostrophe to escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that whilst you might be using a prepared statement, you are not binding parameters. For example, instead of

```
$val = "Some string with an a'postrophe in it";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE table SET col = '$val'");
$stmt->execute();
```

You should use

```
$val = "Some string with an a'postrophe in it";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE table SET col = :val');
$stmt->bindParam('val', $val);
$stmt->execute();
```

or at least

```
$val = "Some string with an a'postrophe in it";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE table SET col = :val');
$stmt->execute(array('val' => $val));
```

This is using named parameters but you can also use positional ones using `?` as a placeholder

Comment: Hey Phil, the last example you provided did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @Jim `PDOStament::bindParam()` only works with variables. To bind a literal, use `PDOStatement::bindValue()` or as shown, pass the values to `PDOStatement::execute()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but this might help with PDO escaping:

```
PDO::quote($data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Suspect you are not using preparred statements correctly, or there is something wrong with your code.

The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) specifically states:

> The parameters to prepared statements
>   don't need to be quoted; the driver
>   automatically handles this. If an
>   application exclusively uses prepared
>   statements, the developer can be sure
>   that no SQL injection will occur
>   (however, if other portions of the
>   query are being built up with
>   unescaped input, SQL injection is
>   still possible).

Comment: I didn't look into it very deeply, I just attempted to insert a string with an apostrophe and it didn't go in. I'm already using prepare and I'm quite certain there isn't anything wrong with my code. I've followed the manual on prepare to the tee/

Comment: @jim Can you can do me a favor, and please post sample code in your question?

Comment: I've posted it up top. Thanks!